# Kendo MVC ListView widget endless scrolling not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, listview, kendo-ui

One of the latest versions of Kendo UI for MVC includes the `.Scrollable(ListViewScrollableMode.Endless)` feature on their ListViews, that is the feature I am having issues with here, other issues with the same title that I could find are in reference to 'home made' solutions in previous versions of Kendo.

My Issue:

I have followed the Kendo Guide here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/listview/endless-scrolling - which explains how to add the endless scrolling to the ListView widget so I eneded up with the following code:

HTML Page:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="reportManagementTemplate">
    <div class="nameBlock">
        <h3 class="nameHeader">#:Username#</h3>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="reportManagementAltTemplate">
    <div class="nameBlock k-alt">
        <h3 class="nameHeader">#:Username#</h3>
    </div>
</script>

<div class="k-content">
    @(Html.Kendo().ListView<Governance.Models.DTO.ReportManagementUsernamesDTO>()
        .Name("ReportUsernameList")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("reportManagementTemplate")
        .ClientAltTemplateId("reportManagementAltTemplate")
        .Selectable(s => s.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Single))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:350px; width: 200px;" })
        .Scrollable(ListViewScrollableMode.Endless)
        .DataSource(datasource =>
        {
            datasource.Read(read => read.Action(MVC.TaskReportManagement.ActionNames.ReportManagementList_Read, MVC.TaskReportManagement.Name));
            datasource.PageSize(9);
        })
    )
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .nameBlock {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

.nameHeader {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

And the read statment returns strings equal to the pagesize that I have set, and when all this code is ran I get this:

[image: Image of my issue]

So as you can see, the items in the listview are going outside of the container around it, can anyone help fix this issue?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you are loading in pages that end up being larger than your container.  Your container height is 350px and if you load 9 strings at 100px each you are going to be at 900px.  Maybe try to do 3 per page to keep the initial load inside the larger container.  The rest of it matches the KendoDemo as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, turns out my scripts were not up to date after I updated kendo, they still pointed to a 2017 folder instead of the 2019. Issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my scripts were not up to date after I updated kendo, they still pointed to a 2017 folder instead of the 2019. Issue is fixed now.